# replacing number at a particular point in text file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file with following content(content is variable to >10 MB) I want to set/replace the copies count to a dynamic number and. I have used sed utiliy to do the same but it will show comand prompt. Is there any way using  C#/regular expression?

How can i write the changed patterns back into file?

> ```
> %-12345X@PJL JOB NAME = "Microsoft Word -Values.docx"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="ComputerName=USER-PC"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="UserName=user"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="PortName=PORTCUSTOM"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="ReceptionTime=22:04:09 2012/02/01"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="DocumentName=Microsoft Word - LDAPValues.docx"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="MultiPage=1"
> @PJL OKIAUXJOBINFO DATA="ApplicationName=Microsoft Office Word"
> @PJL OKIJOBACCOUNTJOB JOBACCOUNTID=0 USERID="user" JOBNAME="Microsoft Word - Values.docx"
> @PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY = ""
> @PJL COMMENT OS Version   : Windows NT 6.1 Build 7600 
> @PJL COMMENT Product Name : OKI PCL5c Printer Driver
> @PJL COMMENT Device Name  : OKI
> @PJL COMMENT Version      : 1.0.5
> @PJL COMMENT Build Date   : 2010/03/30 (Tue) 16:17:01
> @PJL SET OKIPAPERSIZECHECK=ENABLE
> @PJL SET OKICUPAPERSIZECHECK=ENABLE
> @PJL SET MANUALFEED=OFF
> @PJL SET OKIXDIMENSIONMILLIMETER=216
> @PJL SET OKIYDIMENSIONMILLIMETER=280
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCMANUAL=2
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY1=4
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY2=1
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY3=5
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY4=6
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY5=20
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY6=21
> @PJL SET MEDIASRCINTRAY7=22
> @PJL SET QTY=1
> @PJL SET COPIES=2
> @PJL SET OKIRESOLUTION=X600Y600LEVEL2
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This finds the number after "`@PJL SET COPIES=`"

```
(?<=@PJL\ SET\ COPIES=)\d+
```

Use it like this

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=@PJL\ SET\ COPIES=)\d+", newCount.ToString());
```

---

I used the Regex lookaround pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like

```
Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    @"COPIES=\d+", 
    string.Format("COPIES={0}", number), 
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

would do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx

Writing it back into the file will look something like this:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
string output = Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    @"COPIES=\d+", 
    string.Format("COPIES={0}", number), 
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText("filename.txt", output);
```